# Remove the element of jsni through ui binder html panel

Tags: javascript, uibinder

How to remove the element from html panel.

I used htmlgetElementById(id); to get id of the jsni element.

But still i cannot remove it.

How can i do this ?

Comment: it would be so nice if you would have just answered my ques rather than going through my grammatical mistakes. still thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error ??

Answer (score 0):

I have done with this work.

set id of the form you want to remove first.

```
inndiv.id=id;
```

Element el=html.getElementById(Integer.toString(id));
                                        el.removeFromParent();